# How can I create an EMR cluster resource that uses spot instances without hardcoding the bid_price variable?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform to create an AWS EMR cluster that uses spot instances as core instances.

I know I can use the `bid_price` variable within the `core_instance_group` block on a `aws_emr_cluster` resource, but I don't want to hardcode prices as I'd have to change them manually every time the instance type changes.

Using the AWS Web UI, I'm able to choose the **"Use on-demand as max price"** option. That's exactly what I'm trying to reproduce, but in Terraform.

[image: on-demand]

Right now I am trying to solve my problem using the `aws_pricing_product` data source. You can see what I have so far below:

```
data "aws_pricing_product" "m4_large_price" {
  service_code = "AmazonEC2"

  filters {
   field = "instanceType"
   value = "m4.large"
  }

  filters {
   field = "operatingSystem"
   value = "Linux"
  }

  filters {
   field = "tenancy"
   value = "Shared"
  }

  filters {
   field = "usagetype"
   value = "BoxUsage:m4.large"
  }

  filters {
   field = "preInstalledSw"
   value = "NA"
  }

  filters {
    field = "location"
    value = "US East (N. Virginia)"
  }
}
```

`data.aws_pricing_product.m4_large_price.result` returns a `json` containing the details of a single product (you can check the response of the example [here](https://pastebin.com/ZmxsaENN)). The actual on-demand price is buried somewhere inside this json, but I don't know how can I get it (image generated with http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/):

[image: price-json]

I know I might be able solve this by using an external data source and piping the output of an aws cli call to something like jq, e.g:

```sh
aws pricing get-products --filters "Type=TERM_MATCH,Field=sku,Value=8VCNEHQMSCQS4P39" --format-version aws_v1 --service-code AmazonEC2 | jq [........]
```

But I'd like to know if there is any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with pure Terraform. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the [`aws_pricing_product` data source docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/pricing_product.html) don't expand on how it should be used effectively but the [discussion in the pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/5057) that added it adds some insight.

In Terraform 0.12 you should be able to use the [`jsondecode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsondecode.html) to nicely get at what you want with the following given as an example in the linked pull request:

```
data "aws_pricing_product" "example" {
  service_code = "AmazonRedshift"

  filters = [
    {
      field = "instanceType"
      value = "ds1.xlarge"
    },
    {
      field = "location"
      value = "US East (N. Virginia)"
    },
  ]
}

# Potential Terraform 0.12 syntax - may change during implementation
# Also, not sure about the exact attribute reference architecture myself :)
output "example" {
  values = jsondecode(data.json_query.example.value).terms.OnDemand.*.priceDimensions.*.pricePerUnit.USD
}
```

If you are stuck on Terraform <0.12 you might struggle to do this natively in Terraform other than the external data source approach you've already suggested.

Comment: I'm using Terraform 0.12, so that's OK. I tried creating a local variable with value `"${jsondecode(data.aws_pricing_product.m4_large_price.value).terms.OnDemand.*.priceDimensions.*.pricePerUnit.USD}"`, but I've got the following error: **A splat expression (*) cannot be used inside another attribute-only splat
expression**. I tried a few variations of this expression, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

@cfelipe put that `${jsondecode(data.aws_pricing_product.m4_large_price.value).terms.OnDemand.*.priceDimensions.*.pricePerUnit.USD}"` in a Locals

Comment: Hello! I ultimately gave up on managing EMR and went to Databricks. It's a great product for my use case.
That said, thanks for your answer. People like you make this SO awesome! =D